# mongodb java driver 3.0: how to store JSON document

Tags: java, mongodb, driver

Looks basic and simple: A have a JSON string and I want to store it in MongoDB as JSON document.

In java driver 2.xx I could use `com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(String jsonString)` to get *DBObject* and then store it in collection.

In driver 3.0 *JSON.parse* still gives *DBObject*, but rest of API uses *org.bson.Document* class which looks as incompatible with *DBObject*.

How to do it in driver version 3.0?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For `Document` use the [`parse()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/org/bson/Document.html#parse-java.lang.String-) static helper:

```
Document myDoc = Document.parse(jsonString)
```

Comment: How could I miss it? Thank you :)

Comment: Hi. I couldn't find a method for json arrays. using this method with json array string throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

For you problem, you have at least 3 solutions, lets see:

```
private Map<String, Object> map;

private DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject(map);

private Document document = Document.parse(jsonText);
```

The imports of objects are:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
```

There are a difference with Document object, by default it disconsider all null attributes when object is persisted on mongo. The same not ocorres with another two, in your configuration default not.

I hope helped you...